# Javascript/jQuery turn DOM in single object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

`var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');`

The var items contains 'object HTMLCollection'
I want to check if the divs are visible on the screen, I know how to do that, **but I need the divs in different Objects** in jquery/javascript so I can check if the object is in the screen when the user scrolls (I'm using `$( window ).scroll`)

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Loop through the collection.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {item = items.item(i); //item is a `div.item` each iteration}

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this :

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);//element contain the element selected for one iterate
    //here your code to check one div is visible
});
```

Comment: `:visible` does not select for elements that are presently within the viewport, but visible in the entire document object.

Comment: and if you use :

if(element.css({"display"})=="none")

Comment: @Buisson will this state that the element is in the viewport/screen currently.

Comment: sorry I have misunderstanding the term 'visible'

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom `:inview` pseudo-selector, to implement it: https://gist.github.com/Demwunz/2251871

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    inview: function(el) {
        var e = $(el),
            w = $(window),
            wt = w.scrollTop(),
            wb = wt + w.height(),
            et = e.offset().top,
            eb = et + e.height();

        return eb >= wt && et <= wb;
    }
});
```

Then inside `onscroll` handler:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    //do something with: 
    $('.item:inview') // .item elements in viewport
    //or with:
    $('.item:not(:inview)') // .item elements out of viewport
});
```